# IIS Express not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-express

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC 5 project. I've been working for hours on my **localhost , on my local machine**, hitting F5 and seeing changes. Now when I hit F5 I get this error :

> Unable to make the session state request to the
>   session state server. Please ensure that the ASP.NET State service is
>   started and that the client and server ports are the same. If the
>   server is on a remote machine, please ensure that it accepts remote
>   requests by checking the value of
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters\AllowRemoteConnection.
>   If the server is on the local machine, and if the before mentioned
>   registry value does not exist or is set to 0, then the state server
>   connection string must use either 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' as the
>   server name.

I have not changed any configuration or anything. I was just simply coding and pressing F5 and now I get this. Sometimes when I kill IIS in task manager, it works, but only it worked twice. How can I get rid of this error and make IIS work like before? Thanks.

Comment: Can you check that "ASP.NET State Service" is up and running? (Computer Management -> Services)

Comment: @Uriil I'm working on localhost so that there is no "ASP.NET State Service" in Services. Thanks.

Comment: This question is not duplicate! It's about the same error in localhost.

Comment: What's the difference between localhost and production server? If you developing ASP.NET project, you should have ASP.NET installed on you machine, thus you should have "ASP.NET State Service"

Comment: @Uriil I've checked at least 10 times. There is no ASP.NET service in services.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/252622/asp-net-state-service-missing-from-services